# Copy and mark more than one line at once in notepad++

Tags: search, text, copy, notepad++, line

I have a big text file in which I search for lines I need to delete. I manually copy one line than put the mark button and repeat it again, I want to know if it possible to put all lines or at least more than one and mark it all? Maybe something in this way - word1>word2>word3 ets I don't know all combinations sorry
All words (lines) are unique so recording a marco is not a solution.

My text

```
word1 
word2
word3
word4
word5
word2
word5
word4
```

I need to mark lines - word1, word2, word5
I do it manually one by one but I want to mark them all at once, maybe there is a regex for this I'm not sure like [word1, word2, word5] in the Find what area

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73276011/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: I edited, is it good now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of words is not too big, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(?:word1|word2|word5)\b`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          # word boundary
(?:         # non capture group
    word1       # word1
  |           # OR
    word2       # word2
  |           # OR
    word5       # word3
)           # end group
\b          # word boundary
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]